# Angular 6 + Laravel 5.6: CORS Issue with httpClient.post

Tags: angular, post, laravel-5, cors, httpclient

Created an API with Laravel 5.6 and all endpoints work as expected with Postman. The problems began when i started to develop the Angular 6 app. Since i'm working locally, i began to get CORS errors in Chrome no matter the http method used (httpClient). So i created a middleware in Laravel to process the CORS requests. And everything started to worked as expected, so i thought... Now i'm facing other problems.

I'm using Laravel's default controller actions for the CRUD tasks, so i'm mostly using resource routing (Route::resource). For custom methods i'm using Route::post().

Now, the weird thing is that i'm able to **send post request** for custom methods (Route::post), but not to resource routes.

Example:

```
//post requests to custom routes work as expected
Route::post('users/block', 'API\UserController@toggleBlock');
Route::post('users/access', 'API\UserController@sendAccess');

//post requests to resource routes nothing happens
Route::resource('settings', 'API\SettingController');
Route::resource('products', 'API\ProductController');
```

If i change the routes to the following:

```
Route::get('settings', 'API\SettingController@index'); //works!
Route::post('settings', 'API\SettingController@store'); //nothing happens!!
Route::post('settings/bazinga', 'API\SettingController@store'); //works!!
```

So, from what i can tell, i can't use the same URI even thought the http methods are different.

Here is my CORS middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //apply cors only to api routes
    if (Request::segment(1) == 'api') {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Cache-Control',
        ];
        if ($request->isMethod("OPTIONS")) {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
    } else {

        $response = $next($request);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Why is this happening? Is this related to CORS? Since everything works as expected with Postman, this might be related with CORS, right?

**UPDATE: cURL Output**

```
> curl 'https://api.project.localhost:34430/api/settings' -D -X OPTIONS -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'access-control-request-headers: authorization,' -H 'access-control-request-method: POST' -H 'origin: <http://localhost:4200>' -o output.txt
```

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: OPTIONS

**UPDATE #2: Angular Code**

Save Method:

```
save(settings: Setting[]): Observable<any> {
    const path = 'settings';

    const headers = {
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    };

    const params = { settings: settings };

    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.api.post(path, params, headers).subscribe(
            data => {
              // observable execution
              observer.next('Save Settings');
              observer.complete();
        },
        error => console.log(error) // error path
      );
    });
}
```

Post Method:

```
post(path: string, params: Object, headers?: any): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    const request = this.createRequestObject(path, params, headers);

    return this.http.post<ApiResponse>(
        request.endPoint,
        request.params,
        request.httpOptions
    );
}

private createRequestObject(path: string, params?: Object, headers?: any): ApiRequest {
    if (headers) {
      Object.assign(this.headers, headers);
    }

    const request = new ApiRequest();
    request.endPoint = this.endPoint + path;
    request.httpOptions = { headers: this.headers };
    request.params = params;

    return request;
}
```

**UPDATE #3: Chrome Dev Tools Console**

Get Request:

[image: Get Request Console Log]

[image: Get Request Network Activity 1]

[image: Get Request Network Activity 2]

Post Request:

[image: Post Request Console Log]

Note: Nothing happens in Network Activity when i perform the post request.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check from curl or postman what output you are getting for this endpoint with OPTION?

```
curl '<path to endpoint>' -X OPTIONS -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'access-control-request-headers: authorization,' -H 'access-control-request-method: POST' -H 'origin: <http://localhost:4200>'
```

something like above request?

Comment: The output in both Postman and cURL is: OK. I've updated my question with the results.

Comment: please use curl with  `-D-` options to see what response header server is sending

Comment: i get this error: curl: (6) Could not resolve host: OPTIONS

Comment: Meaning your preflight request ie OPTION is getting failed and chrome is giving the cors error.

Comment: Btw, i'm using Passport and i need to send an Authorization token in the header. Can that be the cause of the curl error?

Comment: You need to allow the origin in the cors settings of apps or it is mismatched in someway

Comment: In my CORS middleware i have the following: 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'

Comment: One more varification we can do.please install CORS chrome extension, enable it refresh the tab. Check if it working? This extension bypass cors on your browser. Check this for confirmation

Comment: I dont know much php, i can only help you in angular part and in makin sure that frontend is fine you need to resolve it in php. Or some pointer to tracking where thing can go wrong

Comment: Installed the extension and tried the request with it enabled, but nothing happens :(

Comment: Done! Updated my question with the post request code.

Comment: Alos url path and console.log() from chromedevtool

Comment: Updated my question. Just a note, i've added a Network Activity for the GET request. When i do the POST request, nothing shows up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181776/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-and-ricky).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of passed and required headers. That should be maintained and passed from both side (Client & Server).

Laravel :

You can use the package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors and modify the settings according to requirements.

Angular 6 : You must read https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor. You can create interceptor which will handle the Headers in client side. I am attaching a boilerplate where you can check and use the interceptor. Check the Answer in given Link.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53350123/3851720

Answer (score 0):

In angular end, in service file I've added

```js
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
 })
};
```

before decorators.

And in Laravel end in index.php inside public folder,
just add headers like below

```html
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
```