# Angular 6 Boilerplate with only Basic Features (Required all the time)?

Tags: angular, jwt, angular6, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I Setup Angular all the time with new Project. Anyone can suggest good boilerplate where no need to develop Basic required features which are required most of the times in a application.

1. JWT Authentication in Angular 6
2. Bootstrap/Material Design setup in Angular 6
3. Http Services in Angular 6
4. File Uploading in Angular 6
5. Basic CRUD in Angular 6

Please suggest. It will save my lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow this boilerplate
https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Ready-To-Use-Boilerplate

Just clone this project and run `npm install` and you got all necessary components and a CRUD with JWT authentication as well as commands in readme.md to create new components/services/CRUD operations.

1. All the points are covered in this Repo
2. Friendly CRUD application
3. Functions Boilerplate with Best Practices
4. Readme.md with description
5. Separated Directory Structure

Comment: Sure i will check.

Comment: That is Awesome. Thanks @Shubham

Comment: Updated URL https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use this ngx-rocket/starter-kit

find it here
https://github.com/ngx-rocket/starter-kit